# Why are accumulators sent directly to the driver?

Tags: apache-spark

With Spark, if I've already defined my accumulators to be associative and reducible, why are does each worker send them directly to the driver rather than reducing incrementally along with my actual job? It seems a bit goofy to me.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I think you have a wrong idea how accumulator works. Or do you ask about task results?

Comment: As `broadcast` variables, `accumulators` are pretty useful in several cases.

Answer (score 1):

Each task in Spark maintains its own accumulator and its value is send back to the driver when particular task has been finished.

Since accumulators are in Spark are mostly a diagnostic and monitoring sharing accumulators between tasks would make these almost useless. Not to mention that worker failure after particular task is finished would result in a loss of data and make accumulators even less reliable than they are right now.

Moreover this mechanism is pretty much the same as the standard RDD `reduce` where tasks results are continuously send to the driver and merged locally.

Comment: Right, but let's say that I'm using my accumulator to gain extra information about an elastic search index, specifically which documents have been seen. And lets say that in this index there are many duplicates, ~40%. In this case, having each worker send an accumulator with info about their partition blows up the driver. if the accumulators were to be reduced in the same way that workers reduce their partitions, then by the time the "final" accumulator was sent to the driver, there would be no problem.

Comment: There is no difference here. Both accumulators and tasks results are send after the task is finished. That being said, using growing collection accumulators, especially to implement application logic is not the best idea.

Comment: wait... results from a task are all send to the driver then reduced on the driver? i don't think that's true, i believe reduction is done incrementally between workers until the final reduction is placed on the driver.